# Universal Windows Platform (UWP) equivalent to get main application UI

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2015, windows-10-universal

I am trying to migrate a `Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight` app to `UWP`. I have an error getting the `Main Application UI`.

This is the windows `Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight` code:

```
Storage storage = ((App.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).DataContext as Storage);
```

This is what I've done for the `UWP` version:

```
Storage storage = ((Window.Current.Content as Frame).DataContext as Storage);
```

I get a `NullPointerException`. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

This is my xaml:

```
<Page
x:Class="windows_phone.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="20"
Foreground="#FF000000">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <WebView 
            x:Name="webView" 
            Margin="0,0,0,0" 
            Grid.Row="1" 
            />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

This is my class Store to save the last Uri:

```
 namespace windows
{
public class Storage
{
    #region Properties
    private Uri _lastUri = null;
    public Uri lastUri 
    { 
        get {return _lastUri;} 
        set
        {
            _lastUri = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
}
```

**SECOND EDIT**

Code where I use Store class:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{

   private Storage storage = null;

....

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        storage = (((Window.Current.Content as Frame).Content as Page).DataContext as Storage);
        if (Storage.lastUri != null) webView.Navigate(Storage.lastUri);
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }

    void webView_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (webView.Source.ToString().Contains("login"))
        {
            string id = LoadUserIdFromIsolatedStorage();
            String[] data = new String[1];
            data[0] = id;
            if (id != null)
                webView.InvokeScript("WinHelp", data);
        }
        progressIndicator.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        Storage.lastUri = e.Uri;
    }
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to get the DataContext of the active frame?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Comment: Is this retreived from a code behind file or seperate class?

Comment: Nop, the app is a simple page with a webView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datacontext of the Frame is indeed `NULL`. This because the frame houses the view inside the another content variable. That one will contain your `DataContext`.

You will need to declare the content as a page. Below here is an example:

```
((Window.Current.Content as Frame).Content as Page).DataContext;
```

Comment: I modified the example a bit just a min ago. I forgot to add something. If it still doesn't help, please add extra information to your question. Like where exactly in the app you use it (for example: MainPage.xaml.cs) and what you need it for. With this I can improve my answer.

Comment: I have added a extra information. I have wrote my xaml. The app only contains  a page who is called MainPage.

Comment: Then where do you declare your DataContext? I don't see it in the XAML

Comment: I have edited my question again, maybe now you understand why I didnt write the context in the XAML.

Comment: So you have a model / viewmodel as DataContext. Do you set the DataContext on the constructor of the page or in the onLoaded? Please post that code as well. I think the problem lies there and not with retreiving the DataContext

Comment: I added the code where I use this Store class, it is exactly as my 8.1 app and it works.

Comment: Based on your code the application suspects that the datacontext is present onNavigation, but if you don't initialize the context it will always be null.

Comment: You are completely right!! I added the data context and it works like a charm. Now I am wondering why in the 8.1 version it works as well, but... doesnt matter!! Thank you very much!